# making a user input a number and not allowing them to input a blank input

Tags: javascript

I am making a javascript program in which the program asks the user whether they want to calculate distance, speed or time. The program works but I want to be able to make it where the user cannot enter a blank input as well as not allowing the program to continue if their input is not a number(where numbers are needed)

//This program asks the user to input whether they would like to calculate distance, time or speed.
//Depending their answer they get asked to input the values of the other two options
//The program then calculates either the speed, distance or time

```
function calculate(){
try{
    let question = prompt("Would you like to calculate Distance(km), Time(h) or Speed(kph)");
    let answer = question.toLowerCase();
        if(answer === "distance" && answer != ""){
            let time = Number(prompt("Please enter your time in hours:"));
            let speed = Number(prompt("Please enter your speed:"));
            let calculation = speed * time;
            console.log(`The Distance is: ${calculation} km`);
        }else if(answer === "time" && answer != ""){
            let distance = Number(prompt("Please enter your distance:"));
            speed = Number(prompt("Please enter your speed:"));
            let calculation2 = distance / speed;
            console.log(`Your Time is: ${calculation2} hours`);
        }else if(answer === "speed" && answer != ""){
            distance = Number(prompt("Please enter your distance:"));
            time = Number(prompt("Please enter your time in hours:"));
            calculation3 = distance / time;
            console.log(`Your speed is: ${calculation3} kph`)
        }else{
          calculate();
        }
}catch(e){
calculate();
}
}

let output = calculate();
```

Comment: You will have to use while loops. for example: `While (time is not a number){ prompt user for time}`. To check type of a value, use `typeof`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to separate the functionality and write a generic function which recursively calls itself until a valid input is given.

One of the possible implementation:

```js
function getTypePrompt() {
    const question = prompt("Would you like to calculate Distance(km), Time(h) or Speed(kph)");
    if (question === "") {
        return getTypePrompt();
    }

    if (question === null) {
        return null;
    }

    switch (question) {
        case "distance":
        case "time":
        case "speed":
            return question;
    }

    return getTypePrompt();
}

function getNumberPrompt(message) {
    const response = prompt(message);
    if ((response == null) || (response === "")) {
        return getNumberPrompt(message);
    }

    const data = parseInt(response);

    if (!isNaN(data)) {
        return data;
    }

    return getNumberPrompt(message);
}



try {
    let question = getTypePrompt();
    let answer = question.toLowerCase();
    if (answer === "distance") {
        let time = getNumberPrompt("Please enter your time in hours:");
        let speed = getNumberPrompt("Please enter your speed:");
        let calculation = speed * time;
        document.write(`The Distance is: ${calculation} km`);
    } else if (answer === "time") {
        let distance = getNumberPrompt("Please enter your distance:");
        speed = getNumberPrompt("Please enter your speed:");
        let calculation2 = distance / speed;
        document.write(`Your Time is: ${calculation2} hours`);
    } else if (answer === "speed") {
        distance = getNumberPrompt("Please enter your distance:");
        time = getNumberPrompt("Please enter your time in hours:");
        calculation3 = distance / time;
        document.write(`Your speed is: ${calculation3} kph`)
    } else {
        document.write("You have cancelled the calculation");
    }
} catch (e) {
    document.write("Something went wrong!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let 
  time,
  speed,
  calculation;

time = Number(prompt("Please enter your time in hours:"));

if(!time) {
  time = Number(prompt("Please enter your time in hours:"));
}

speed = Number(prompt("Please enter your speed:"));

if(!speed) {
  speed = Number(prompt("Please enter your speed:"));
}
```

You can replace the Number by adding + just before prompting.
`time = +(prompt("Please enter your time in hours:"));`

If you want a faster, thought less clearer sometimes, you can use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator)

which is basically like a short if-else

```
time = !time ? +(prompt("Please enter your time in hours:")); : time;
```